# What is correct interpretation of Bhagavad gita 9:32?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Gita 9:32

> O son of Prtha, those who take shelter in Me, though they be of **lower birth-women**, vaisyas [merchants], as well as sudras [workers]-can approach the supreme destination.

What is correct interpretation of Bhagavad gita 9:32?

Answer (score 6):

> मां हि पार्थ व्यपाश्रित्य येऽपि स्युः पापयोनयः।
>   स्त्रियो
>   वैश्यास्तथा शूद्रास्तेऽपि यान्ति परां गतिम्।।9.32।।
>
> māṁ hi pārtha vyapāśritya ye ’pi syuḥ pāpa-yonayaḥ
>   striyo vaiśyās
>   tathā śūdrās te ’pi yānti parāṁ gatim
>
> O son of Pṛthā, those who take shelter in Me, though they be of lower
>   birth – women, vaiśyas [merchants] and śūdras [workers] – can attain
>   the supreme destination.

It is clearly declared here by the Supreme Lord that in devotional service there is no distinction between the lower and higher classes .
**Everyone is eligible for the supreme destination(moksha).**

According to the different modes of material nature, men are classiﬁed as
brāhmaṇas , kṣatriyas, vaiśyas and śūdras.
Those lower than them are called caṇḍālas, and they are born in sinful families.**But the process of devotional service is so strong that the pure devotee of the Supreme Lord can enable people of all the lower classes to attain the highest perfection of life.**

So the actual  meaning and purpose of this shloka is those   who are sinners  among Women , Vaishya and shudras  and even those who are lower than them can attain the highest perfection through pure devotion of god.

Comment: Shreemad Bhagvat purana is agreeing with above verse.

Comment: @swiftpushkar how does a yoni becomes papa yoni?

Comment: It depends upon karmas of past life of a person. As hinduism believes in Karma and Rebirth theory.Its considered that , the person having done some bad deeds in previous lives ,gets birth among sinners again either to repay or to continue his journey further.

Comment: **those who are sinners among Women** So that means there are **no sinners among men** Right?

Comment: @Secret -  No its not like that. Off course there are sinners among men of all the  varnas. But the purpose and the context of the verse is not to talk about that subject  here at that pace. See every chapter and every verse has some association with specific topic it is dealing  , so here the topic is of libation to all (including sinners) among all , who are pure devotes of the lord.

Comment: @Secret - Various men who can be called sinners among all the varnas are discussed in different texts like smirities ,  puranas etc.. So basically we need to know this first in order to understood the meaning of this BG verse.We cant conclude as such just by looking at one verse of one book. So Comprehensive reading is also necessary in order to understand our whole scriptures.

Comment: Its already having a duplicate... Why are people in a hurry to answer

Comment: You dont have time to respond to.my posts in room but have timw to write long answers

Answer (score 0):

> मां हि पार्थ व्यपाश्रित्य येऽपि स्युः **पापयोनयः**।
>    स्त्रियो वैश्यास्तथा शूद्रास्तेऽपि यान्ति परां गतिम्।।9.32।।

This shloka is mostly misinterpreted by many people.

The word pāpa-yonayaḥ (पापयोनयः) indicates to unholy union and a baby born from unholy union is a sinner.

The word स्त्रियो means women. Women tends to be attracted towards materialistic thing. A women will love her child and her family the most in this world. These are all materialistic things.

The word वैश्याः is referring to vaishyas. Vaishyas are people who live to make profit because they are business minded people. They will lie to earn profit. Vaishyas are also attracted towards materialistic things.

The word शूद्रा (shudras) refers to fourth traditional varna (social class). Shudras are people who work for people of higher social class like brahmanas. They do work like cleaning, picking wastes etc., as a result sudras are not very clean.
The reason why Shudras work hard is because they are attached to the fruits of their own efforts and as a result shudras are also attracted towards materials.

So, Lord Krishna says those who are born from unholy union, those who are attracted towards materialistic **(pointing to women, vaishyas, shudras)** thing can attain their supreme destination through pure devotion of god.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. The word is `वैश्यास्तथा` that is `वैश्य:+तथा` not `वैश्या`

Comment: oh, ok . I got what you were pointing. I have edited the post.
That was a very stupid mistake i made, haha can't stop laughing.

Comment: That is why i said this sloka is misinterpreted at the very top of my answer. 
Lord Krishna is saying those who focus on materialistic thing cannot attain the supreme destination.
Women gets attracted to materials quite quickly, it does not matter whether they are brahmans or shudras or vaishyas. 
Vaishyas ( both men and women) will move in a direction where they could make some gain.
Lord Krishna says, You need to throw your desire if you want to reach supreme destination

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. I was pointing to your mistake which you have edited now.

Comment: @WhatIsThatException Its a mistranslation. Refer to Sankara bhashya. papayoni means born sinners. Next verse talks of punya yoni